# Wordpress Nginx + Apache reverse Proxy permalinks

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, wordpress

Allow me to explain my problem.  I have a Ubuntu VPS server running 18.04 I have installed Nginx and Apache with php-fpm I've configured Nginx to be a reverse proxy for my wordpress blog located at https://mydomainname.com/blog this is all working fine.  however I have been unable to get my permalinks to work my config for my server block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://%host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/;


    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;


ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;


 ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;



    location /blog/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args =404;



        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;


        proxy_redirect off;

    }

}
```

My Apache Vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerName mydoamin.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
   SetHandler "proxy:unix:///var/run/php7.2-fpm-mydomain.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1/"
</FilesMatch>

    <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

      Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: return 301 https://%host$request should % not an dollar?

Comment: I tried that and it did not work

Comment: you really needs to put more output what does not work

Comment: please give us more output

Answer (score 2):

I have now resolved this.  The problem was I had forgotten to enable Mod-ReWrite for Apache.  I've also updated my Nginx Conf to be:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/;
    #index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;


ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;


 ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

access_log            /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;


location / {
return 301 https://$host/blog/;
}

    location /blog/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;


        proxy_redirect off;

    }

}
```